# Error al publicar mi servicio WCF

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

Tengo un problema al momento de publicar mi servicio WCF en mi servidor, locamente ejecuta sin ningún problema pero al momento de publicarlo genera el siguiente error.

> El servicio 'servicio' tiene cero extremos de aplicación (no
>   infraestructura). Esto puede deberse a que no se encontró ningún
>   archivo de configuración para la aplicación, a que no se encontró
>   ningún elemento de servicio coincidente con el nombre del servicio en
>   el archivo de configuración, o bien a que no se definió ningún extremo
>   en el elemento de servicio.

Todo parece indicar que es de mi Web.Config pero no encuentro el problema,
Este es mi Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="policyInjection" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.Configuration.PolicyInjectionSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
    <section name="exceptionHandling" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Configuration.ExceptionHandlingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>
  <policyInjection>
    <policies>
      <add name="PoliticaFachada">
        <handlers>
          <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.PolicyInjection.LogCallHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" beforeMessage="------------" afterMessage="Error" severity="Error" name="PoliticaFachada">
            <categories>
              <add name="General" />
            </categories>
          </add>
        </handlers>
      </add>
      <add name="PoliticaArchivo">
        <handlers>
          <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.PolicyInjection.LogCallHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" beforeMessage="------------" afterMessage="Error" severity="Error" name="PoliticaArchivor">
            <categories>
              <add name="Archivo" />
            </categories>
          </add>
        </handlers>
      </add>
    </policies>
  </policyInjection>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General">
    <listeners>
      <add name="RollingFileException" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="C:\Desarrollo\CUBEX\WCFServicios\WcfFacturaElectronica\WcfFacturaElectronica\LOGS\wSCubex_Error.log" footer="--------------------FOOTER------------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" header="--------------------HEADER--------------------" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" rollSizeKB="100000" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" />
      <add name="RollingFileExceptionArchivo" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" fileName="C:\Desarrollo\CUBEX\WCFServicios\WcfFacturaElectronica\WcfFacturaElectronica\LOGS\Errores.log" footer="-----------------FOOTER-----------------------" formatter="Text Formatter" header="-----------------HEADER-------------------------" rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Timestamp: {timestamp}{newline}&#xA;Message: {message}{newline}&#xA;Category: {category}{newline}&#xA;Priority: {priority}{newline}&#xA;EventId: {eventid}{newline}&#xA;Severity: {severity}{newline}&#xA;Title:{title}{newline}&#xA;Machine: {localMachine}{newline}&#xA;App Domain: {localAppDomain}{newline}&#xA;ProcessId: {localProcessId}{newline}&#xA;Process Name: {localProcessName}{newline}&#xA;Thread Name: {threadName}{newline}&#xA;Win32 ThreadId:{win32ThreadId}{newline}&#xA;Extended Properties: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}" name="Text Formatter" />
    </formatters>
    <logFilters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.CategoryFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="Error">
        <categoryFilters>
          <add name="General" />
        </categoryFilters>
      </add>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Filters.CategoryFilter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="SeguridadFunciona" />
    </logFilters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="RollingFileException" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
      <add switchValue="All" name="Archivo">
        <listeners>
          <add name="RollingFileExceptionArchivo" />
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events" />
      <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category" />
      <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="RollingFileException" />
          <add name="RollingFileExceptionArchivo" />
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="PoliticaFachada">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="None">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="ArchivoException" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling" formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling" priority="0" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
          <add name="SqlException" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="None">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="ArchivoExceptionSql" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" logCategory="General" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling" formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling" priority="0" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
      <add name="PoliticaArchivo">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" postHandlingAction="None">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="Logging Exception Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" logCategory="Archivo" eventId="100" severity="Error" title="Enterprise Library Exception Handling" formatterType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.TextExceptionFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling" priority="0" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="name" connectionString="Data Source=192.0.0.0;Initial Catalog=xxxxx; Integrated Security=False; User Id=SqlCubexService;Password=xxxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="name" connectionString="Data Source=192.0.0.0;Initial Catalog=xxxxx; Integrated Security=False; User Id=SqlCubexService;Password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="RutaLog" value="C:\Fuentes\Cubex\WsCubex\LOG_WCF_FACTURAELECTRONICA" />
    <add key="PrefijoFacturaVenta" value="PRUE" />
    <add key="PrefijoFacturaVentaExpor" value="PRUE" />
    <add key="PrefijoNotaCredito" value="NCPR" />
    <add key="PrefijoNotaDebito" value="NDPR" />
    <add key="PrefijoNotaCreditoDevolucion" value="PRUE" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="InvoiceServiceImplServiceSoapBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="StreamedRequest"
              useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
                maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>      
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>-->    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>  
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Interception" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Practices.Unity" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Necesito una ayuda gracias de ante mano.

Comment: end donde estas declarando tu endpoint?

Comment: no están? debe tener algún endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en tu archivo de configuracion debe estar declarado un simple end point como sigue:

```
         behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 

         contract="MyWCFServices.IHelloWorldService"/>
      <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" 

         binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
  </service>
```

tambien puede agregarse desde codigo

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost/HelloWorldService.svc"));
var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory(binding, endpoint);
var serviceClient = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
var result = serviceClient.Ping("Ping");
channelFactory.Close();
```

Comment: Gracias, fue muy útil para mi!